# How to change banner 260x260 in Indicate-2.1 Themes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When i download and install themes. I see `Secondary Sidebar` that have some widget defaults

I go to `Appearance\Widgets` to change `Secondary Sidebar`

I want to change banner(260x260) (i draw a red box below)

But i can't find it in `Appearance\Widgets`. How can i do that thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to edit your your editor file under the appearance tag at the left side bar menu from their you need to remove that banner. or one thing more you try you check what is this open your site in Mozilla Firefox and their you use firebug add-on and check what CSS is Applying to that banner after once you search what CSS their you are going to your style sheet and search the tag that should be apply their. write their a code Display:none. in that tag your banner is auto remove from their.